# Cloud Service Or Iaas or Paas

Tags: cloud, saas, paas, iaas

I would like to develop a cloud solution , where multiple users login to the computing nodes to work on established big data clusters ,I am a beginner Could anyone please suggest open source technologies with which I can manage my entire cloud environment,where  i should be able to

*Managing the users logins
*Providing very constrained access to users
*Any roll back mechanism in case of catastrophic  events 
*Able to collect usage information of each user ,event logs and able to bill 
*If any network specifications recommended to accommodate more than 150 users.
*How do I route users who logged into a web service to the compute node

Thanks very much for your kind help !

Thanks

Comment: Just to clear concepts: IaaS, PaaS and SaaS are cloud services.  In this case, you want to build a SaaS or multitenant arquitecture.

Comment: Hi Eleazar ,  Thank you  so much your kind response  Its a kind of all because I have built a hadoop cluster on   high compute nodes  like servers and desktops that manage to store some TB's data  bind by hadoop cluster ,My requirement is to make the cluster available with strict permissions ,where users can login remotely and develop their own jobs to run on hadoop cluster ,I need to manage at least 100+ users ,Its a kind of more a PAAS or SAAS rather than saying it IAAS , and it is true that it is a SAAS and Mutlitenant .Thanks alot for you help

Answer (score 0):

Openstack with packstack is one of the best options  to configure the cloud can be deployed very quickly using RDOs but you may ran into issues related to puppet,rabbitmq-server ,mariadb and httpd  make sure you have configured your static ip and network accordingly

Thanks